# Question about server-to-server notification

Tags: in-app-purchase

As Apple doc said in this doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/notification_type?changes=_2

```
Subscription event                             | Notification types triggered
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
.
.
.
Auto-renewal disabled (canceled) from 
the App Store account's Subscriptions settings | DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS

AppleCare refund                               | CANCEL, DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS
```

When AppleCare `refund` happend, there are two notification types triggered, one of them is `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS`. And when `cancel subscription` happened, its notification type is `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` too. So, when i got a notification with notification_type `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS`, how could i know whether the user has `refunded` or `canceled`?

Comment: And why there are twe types when `AppleCare refund ` happend? It is confusing. I am always thinking just `CANCEL` notification type will be received when refund happen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Apple triggers `CANCEL` as well as `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS`, but technical it is correct. The user cancels his subscription (you get the `CANCEL` notification) and this also changes the renewal status (you get the `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` notification—obviously the subscription won't renew in the future).

To your question: you know a refund happend when you receive the `CANCEL` notification and when the server response body with the `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` notification contains the `cancellation_date_ms` in `Latest_receipt_info`.

> **cancellation_date_ms**
>
> The time and date that Apple customer support canceled a transaction or the time and date the user upgraded an auto-renewable subscription.

see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/cancellation_date_ms?language=data) for more details.

Don't worry in the case that a user upgrades his subscription, your server will receive additionally to `CANCEL` and `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` the `INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL` notification.

In the case the user canceled (deactivated auto-renew) the field `auto_renew_status` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/auto_renew_status)) in the response body is set to `0`.

Comment: Can i understand like this: When a notification_type `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` received, check if there is a `cancellation_date_ms` in `latest_receipt_info`, if there is , i consider Apple refunded, if not, i check the `auto_renew_status`, if its value is `0`, i consider user has deactivated subscription.

Comment: Yes. But when you receive `INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL` you need to check if it is for a previously as cancelled marked subscription, because this means the user upgraded to a new subscription instead of that Apple's customer service granted him a refund