# Detecting IAP Cancellation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase

I generally understand receipt validation on In App Purchases. Most libraries make this as simple as calling a method.

I'm not so clear on how subscriptions work though -- specifically, how can I detect if the subscription is cancelled?

Subscriptions are cancelled on Apple's iTunes interface only. How is my server supposed to know that a subscription was cancelled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Apple docs:

> The user can also cancel their subscription by disabling auto-renew and intentionally letting their subscription lapse. This action triggers the App Store to send your server a status update notification of type `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS`. Your server can parse the `auto_renew_status` and the `auto_renew_status_change_date` to determine the current renewal status of the subscription.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/handling_subscriptions_billing#3221914

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Jacob is correct for the case that the user disables the auto-renewal of his subscription. If the user requested a refund from Apple and they cancel the subscription for him. Your server will receive a `CANCEL` notification and the receipt will contain a `cancellation_date` field.

You need to handle both of those cases, because when the user cancels (deactives the auto-renewal) his subscription, it is still valid (till it expires). When Apple customer support cancels the subscription, then it is from this point on invalid.

Note: the `CANCEL` notification is also triggered when a user up- or downgrades to a different subscription of the same subscription group. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60383505/1128713) for more details on that.